# Pressing a key to find its identifier

Tags: vim

In Emacs, I can press `C-h k` and then type a key to find out the key's identifier. (E.g. Emacs `C-h k <CR>` would tell me that Emacs name for `<CR>` is `RET`.

Is there an equivalent to `C-h k` in vim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [vim book](http://iccf-holland.org/click5.html#oualline) in Appendix-B there is a list of special keys.

and also there is a note there

```
If you want to find the name of a key on the keyboard,
you can go into Insert mode and press CTRL-K key
The <> name of the key will be inserted.
This works for the function keys and many other keys.
```

Comment: @Natan:  That is correct: `^M` is terminal key code for `Enter`.

Comment: This also possible in Command-line mode (as well as in Normal mode): press `Ctrl`+`V`, then the key combination.

Comment: @Natan: sure. E.g. `:map ^M o` where `^M` is a literal ctrl-M character and is entered by pressing ctrl+V followed by the Enter key (or <C-V><Enter> in Vim notation). You can create the same mapping by entering `:map <Enter> o` where `<Enter>` is typed out a character at a time. `<CR>` is a synonym for `<Enter>`.